# Static variable in a namespace

Tags: c++, static, namespaces

I'm writing a game framework and I'm trying to generalize and encapsulate platform dependent code like the renderer so that it makes it a bit easier to port. I'm trying to accomplish this while still having a clean way of using the framework. I'm currently having a problem with static variables and namespaces...

```
    // Renderer.h

    namespace Renderer
    {
        static IRenderer* g_pRenderer = NULL;

        static IRenderer* Get(void) { return g_pRenderer; }

        static IRenderer* CreateD3DRenderer()
        {
            g_pRenderer = new RendererD3D(); // Derived from IRenderer
            return g_pRenderer;
        }
    }
```

So in my `main()`, I can call `CreateD3DRenderer()` and it returns an instance just fine; `g_pRenderer` is holding its value since it's being created and returned within the scope of its function... However, `Renderer::Get()` returns `NULL`. Removing `'static'` from the init of `g_pRenderer` causes clashes when used  in other files.

What's going on?

Answer (score 2):

First off, void in an argument list is only necessary in C. In C++, you'd just write `Get()`.

As for the main question, `static` variables are restricted to the compilation unit. Since you put them in a header, this results in a separate variable being created for every compilation unit (i.e. every cpp file) where it is included. You get errors when you remove the `static` part because then you have multiple variables with the same name, leading to a linking error.

If you want a single variable to be shared between multiple files, you use `extern`. However, this is considered bad practice. You're better off refactoring so you don't need global variables like that.

Comment: I don't have any other variables using the same name. Though, technically, it does get re-declared upon including the header this code is in, so I understand that much. But otherwise, this is the only variable of this name in the program.

Answer (score 2):

You should keep all definitions of functions in `.cpp` files, instead of `.h`

What is happening is that when static is used in that fashion, the function or variable is restricted to that `.cpp` file, which means that `g_pRenderer` is different in each `.cpp` file. Multiple definition doesnt happen since each definition is restricted to one `.cpp` file.

You need to remove it to get your global pointer to work. You can keep the static on the getter function, but I would remove it. You should move the definition of the function and the global variable to a `.cpp` file and keep just a declaration of each in the `.h`. Declare the variable as `extern`.